# What is wrong with this picture?

Tags: c

[This is the program] https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcoAO.png)

So, I know how to declare a variable in c. I know that double* means it is only a pointer. But I didn't declare it as a pointer. This is happening on both my laptop and pc, all of a sudden, nothing I'm writing is working and I don't understand what changed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as an image.   Please include details as to what you're trying to do and what isn't working.  What does ```printf("Startnum = %lf", &x);``` do?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I know that double* means it is only a pointer. But I didn't declare it as a pointer." In your own words, where the code says `&x`, what do you think the `&` means? You say that you "didn't declare it as a pointer" - I assume that by "it" you mean the `x` variable, and that you are saying that you declared `x` to be a `double`. What do you think should be the type of `&x`, in that case? Why?

Comment: "I don't understand what changed." Do you see how the error message from the compiler is repeating the wrong line from your code, *underlining parts of that line*, and *labelling* those parts with types? Do you see how those labels relate to the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On line number 16, i.e. the printf() functions...the syntax for a printf function to output something is not to use pointer.

`printf("Something %lf", &x)` here `&x` means address of the variable x and not the value of x.

You simply need to use `printf("Something %lf", x)` this outputs the value of x.

Now, why address of is used in scanf is because it says so. `scanf("%d", &x)` means that read an integer and store it in the address of variable `x`. But while using `printf` we need not use the address of variable to display the value.

Another way you can display the value is `printf("Something %lf", *(&x))`

The `&` operator is used for determining the address of a variable and `*` operator is used as value at location. Thus the expressiong `*(&x)` boils down to the value stored at the address of varuable `x` which is same as the value of `x`.

Comment: Nice explaination